# How to develop a layout Like Google Plus member profile page in android

Tags: android, scroll

I want to develop a Layout like Google Plus implement for member profile page.

Can you please help me in doing so, how can I implement that layout in android.

Comment: Hii, I have tried Collapsing toolbar layout with viewpager but this is not giving me that type of layout.

Can you please help me in developing a layout like google plus uses for it's member profile page.

Thank you so much... :)

Comment: Can you please help me in developing a layout like google plus profile page. It will be a great help.

Comment: I have tried the example shown here http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/ but it does not fulfill my requirements.

I have also tried Collapsing toolbar layout with viewpager and TabLayout but still have some issues in this.

Please guide  me here to achieve exactly the same page as Google plus provide for it's member profile page.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: If you have any idea then please help me here.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: My requirements are exactly the same as we have google plus profile page,   I have tried to implement this using the above link but the parallax effect is not working fine here. With Collapsing toolbar layout I can handle everything but I need to show tabs on image and want to show a circular image also on the same image, that thing I am not able to handle.